# Featuretools - unable to add relationship in Entityset

Tags: python, feature-engineering, featuretools, entityset

I'm writing a notebook using [this data from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-credit-default-risk/data). Here's a screenshot of the two tables just to show we have ID columns in both.
[image]

Here's my code when trying to set up the Entity Set and add a relationship.

```
import featuretools as ft 
import pandas as pd

es = ft.EntitySet()
es = es.add_dataframe(dataframe=train_sampled, index='new_index', dataframe_name='application', make_index=True)
es = es.add_dataframe(dataframe=bureau, index='new_index', dataframe_name='bureau', make_index=True)

new_relationship = ft.Relationship(entityset=es,parent_dataframe_name='application',parent_column_name='SK_ID_CURR',
                    child_dataframe_name='bureau',child_column_name='SK_ID_CURR')
es = es.add_relationship(new_relationship)
```

And here's the error I'm getting that doesn't make any sense.

> KeyError: 'DataFrame <Relationship: bureau.SK_ID_CURR ->
> application.SK_ID_CURR> does not exist in entity set'

The Entityset exists but just can't add a relationship, which is the whole point of this.
[image]

Any advice or guidance is much appreciated.

**EDIT: Solution**
This code uses the answer below plus changes the index column in the bureau table to the correct one that is unique.

```
es = ft.EntitySet()
es = es.add_dataframe(dataframe=train_sampled, index='SK_ID_CURR', dataframe_name='application', make_index=False)
es = es.add_dataframe(dataframe=bureau, index='SK_ID_BUREAU', dataframe_name='bureau', make_index=False)

new_relationship = ft.Relationship(entityset=es,parent_dataframe_name='application',parent_column_name='SK_ID_CURR',
                    child_dataframe_name='bureau',child_column_name='SK_ID_CURR')
es = es.add_relationship(relationship=new_relationship)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding a relationship to an `EntitySet` by passing in a `Relationship` object, you need to make sure to use the `relationship` keyword in your call like this:

```
es.add_relationship(relationship=new_relationship)
```

Without using the `relationship` keyword, the method is expecting that you are passing in four values indicating `parent_dataframe_name`, `parent_column_name`, `child_dataframe_name`, `child_column_name`. Using this approach you could alternatively skip creating the `Relationship` object and add the relationship like this:

```
es.add_relationship('application', 'SK_ID_CURR', 'bureau', 'SK_ID_CURR')
```

Finally, you can also use the `EntitySet.add_relationships` method to add your relationship, which allows you to add one or more relationships to an `EntitySet` by passing in a list of `Relationship` objects:

```
es.add_relationships([new_relationship])
```

For more details on all of these methods and the expected arguments, you can always refer to the [Featuretools API Reference](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/generated/featuretools.EntitySet.add_relationship.html#featuretools.EntitySet.add_relationship)

Comment: The other detail I missed is that the index needs to be unique and isn't required to be the match column between the two dfs. In fact in a one-to-many merge they can't be the same. I changed the index in bureau to SK_ID_BUREAU plus followed your note and it works now.